# MSSQL, PHP update Column to varbinary from navchar error

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, laravel-5

So I have this table column `AgentsView (varbinary(max), null)`

And I'm trying to update that column with a new binary, but i keep getting this error `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

I have tried numerous things to bypass this obstacle. Here is a few attempts that generates the same errormessage

```
update [dbo].[Agents] set [AgentsView] = 0x1EFBBBF3C587472615365726
update [dbo].[Agents] set [AgentsView] = '0x1EFBBBF3C587472615365726'
update [dbo].[Agents] set [AgentsView] = '1EFBBBF3C587472615365726'
update [dbo].[Agents] set [AgentsView] = Cast('1EFBBBF3C587472615365726' as varbinary(max))
update [dbo].[Agents] set [AgentsView] = Convert(varbinary(max), '1EFBBBF3C587472615365726')
update [dbo].[Agents] set [AgentsView] = Convert(varbinary(max), 0x1EFBBBF3C587472615365726)
update [dbo].[Agents] set [AgentsView] = Convert(varbinary(max), '0x1EFBBBF3C587472615365726')
```

I am using PHP and have also tried to cast the variable like this

```
$newData = (binary) . "1EFBBBF3C587472615365726"
```

But i cant understand why I am still getting the same message as before.

Any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Agents](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [AgentsView] [varbinary](max) NULL
)
```

Then run:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Agents] VALUES
(1, NULL)
```

And then update from PHP page:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$serverName = "SERVER\TEST";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false ) {
   echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$tsql1 = "UPDATE [dbo].[Agents] SET [AgentsView] = 0x1EFBBBF3C587472615365726 WHERE id = 1";

$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql1);
if( $stmt1 === false ) {
    echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt1);
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

I got no errors and in `Agents` table:

```
id  AgentsView
1   0x1EFBBBF3C587472615365726
```

So, how do you get this value that you are trying to write into your table? can you show your PHP code?

Comment: Hi gofr1, thanks for the rapid response. Intresting. Well I am using laravel.

`$dbo_profile_from = Dbo_agents::select("AgentsView")->where("x", $request["x])->take(1)->first();

Dbo_agents::where(xxx)->Update([
'AgentsView' => $dbo_profile_from->agentsView
]);`

So this basicly just copies a value from another ROW

Comment: Have you tried to trace what is passed to `$dbo_profile_from->agentsView`? `var_dump`?

Comment: Of course, `string(20334) "EFBBBF3C587472615365726"`. The string is to long to be posted here on stackoverflow, but im showing you the same bit. Ive tried to call it with `Cast` and `Convert` but the dump always shows as string, even with PHP's (binary) didnt change it